# Rest-assured. Expect array element with more then one property value defined

Tags: rest-assured

For example we have JSON in our response:

> `{"data":[{"id":1,"active":false},{"id":2,"active":true}]}`

By using

> `expect().body("data", hasItem(hasEntry("id", 1)))`

we can check, if 'data' array holds element with id=1.

But how we can check, if 'data' array holds element with id=1 that is 'active' (id=1 && active=true)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
get("/data").then().body("data.find { it.id == 1 }.active", is(true));
```